# Installing Stock Android Gingerbread 2.3.x on LG Optimus 2x

Tags: android

I have a question that I've first googled a lot but still confuses me:

Can I install Android Gingerbread stock (basic official Google version) on my LG Optimus 2x? I've found some articles titled "Stock Android on LG Optimus 2x" or something like this, but they all tell me to download some custom Android rom/build, and I'm kindda lost in the jargon there, plus I don't see how downloading a custom LG made ROM/Android means I'm installing stock Android. So again, can someone please tell if and how I can get the same Android that comes with the Nexus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, well, I finally decided to install Cyanogen mod. It's not as good as the stock Android (I had both on my old Nexus one, and having the latest version of stock android was always better then the last version of Cyanogen), but it does have some cool features over it: it let's you do super user stuff, such as over/under clocking your CPU.

I basically followed to the letter the instructions on the cyanogen site:

http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/LG_Optimus_2X:_Full_Update_Guide

with the following remarks:

1. Backup: I didn't do any actual full backup. I just copied some ringtones to my laptop, and exported all my contacts and copied that file to my laptop also
2. In the chapter titled "Flashing CyanogenMod" there's to ways to go about it. I first tried the 2nd one, the one called "Method via ROM Manager" (coz it seemed more elegant), but that just didn't work for me: the last step said "The LG Optimus 2X will now reboot into the recovery, wipe data and cache, and then install CyanogenMod. When it's finished installing it will reboot into CyanogenMod." Yeah, it booted into recovery mode and then nothing happend. However the first alternative, "Method via Recovery" works just fine. There's only one point to that: when the boot menu appears, before you start doing the stuff such as wipe data and choose update.zip, make sure your phone is not connected via USB to laptop, as (at least with mine) if it is the loading bars of any operation will just remain at 0%, no error, nothing happends. However if the thing is not connected via usb all works fine.

Good luck, and if you screw something up and your phone don't boot no more:) don't worry about it, just search on google how to whipe data and cache and restore factory settings and it will be back to the original android, and you can retry the whole thing all over again.

Comment: And as a final quirk: If you install Cyanogen7 "as is" it will change the mounting points of your sdcard and internal storage (the sdcard is no longer at /sdcard but at /emmc/someting....). Now this might work ok for you, or you may have issues when sharing the sdcard via USB. If the latter is an issue for you just download and apply the SDCARD-EMMC-signed.zip as the guy sais in this forum post: http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-1058254-p-8.html (search for "emmc" in the page)

Answer (score 0):

So basically a custom rom is a custom build of an operating system. So in order to get Gingerbread or any other version of android on your phone, you need to install it, and to install it, you need access to recovery mode. Which is basically bios for your phone. So long story short, to get a custom rom, you need the following:

1. Rooted phone. Often done with SuperOneClick on the LG Optimus.
2. Recovery Mode. I would suggest using the App RomManager, which will have you install a custom recovery mode.
3. A custom rom. The most popular for most phones is CyangenMod 7. http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?type=nightly&device=p990

Comment: Yes, agreed, I stumbled in my searches on a very nice and detailed page on the cyanogen site telling me how to specifically install that on my Optimus. However I don't wanna install cyanogen, I want stock android you know the one from Google, not some 3rd party distro/build, like cyanogen or the one made by LG (with which the phone comes by default). It's like saying I want Canonical's Ubuntu, not Kubuntu or any other "mutation"

Comment: Because the LG version of android sucks, it's slow, it has an antivirus I can't uninstall, and it's android 2.2

Comment: I am pretty sure the idea of a "stock google" rom is near impossible unless someone optimized it for the Optimus. There is a reason that there are 40 versions of cm7, and not 1. Also, if you are unsatisfied with cm7, there are many other roms out there.

Comment: Yep I get that now. So basically stock android can be installed on the official devices, such as the Nexus series phones. For all others you either use the custom android made by the manufacturer, or you look for another custom android taylored to your phone's model